# Не работает считывание из файла Java

Tags: java, файлы

```
 List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("save.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
 String lists = lines.get(0);
```

Вот такой небольшой код при выполнении показывает ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at slovar.Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

Ошибка в этой строчке: `String lists = lines.get(0);`
Я так понял, дело в надписи `Size: 0` в ошибке, но дело в том, что файл не пустой, там одна строчка, которую я не могу считать.

Comment: Проверьте сначала существует файл или нет. Возможно у вас проблема с путем к файлу, такое бывает если вы пытаетесь читать файл из папки с ресурсами.

Comment: у вас файл пустой

Comment: пришлите содержимое вашего файла

Comment: такого файла нет или он лежит в другом месте, укажите путь к файлу с корневого каталога.

Comment: "src/main/java/save.txt" примерно так

Comment: @RomanC вряд ли. иначе ошибка была бы:NoSuchFileException

Comment: @Санаев Я посмотрел javadoc там нет такого.

Comment: @RomanC Роман, .IndexOutOfBoundsException - это выход за пределы массива

Comment: @Санаев Причина ясна `дело в надписи Size: 0`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76790/discussion-between--and-roman-c).

Answer (score 2):

Если вы говорите про то, что у вас файл непустой (ошибка говорит обратное)

Проблема может быть, если в вашем проекте несколько файлов с именем `size.txt` и один из них - пустой. Попробуйте в поиске найти дублирующие файлы и удалить их.

Ваш файл должен находиться в ресурсах (это хорошая практика), переместите ваш файл в ресурсы и измените код на:

```
 List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(Main.class.getResource("save.txt").toURI()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String lists = lines.get(0);
```

Comment: Вы же сами писали, что в случае отсутствия файла будет проброшено `NoSuchFileException`. Зачем же тогда говорить о том, что возможная причина в неправильном пути?

Comment: @Regent это вторая ошибка. путь у автора прописан не правильно

Comment: Почему же сразу неправильно? Если код запускается из IDE, то достаточно чтобы файл с таким названием был в корневой папке проекта (по крайней мере, в NetBeans так). Если запускается самостоятельно - то рядом с .jar файлом. Да, иногда лучше чтобы файл был в ресурсах, но не более того.

Comment: Не иногда, а хорошей практикой текстовые файлы, конфигурации и т д располагать именно в ресурсах.

Comment: @Санаев В вопросе ничего не сказано о файле. И вы не можете применить ваш код к любому файлу, где бы он не находился.

Comment: @RomanC Если файл будет находиться в ресурсах, то код будет аналогичным. Единственное только вместо Main.class будет имя класса, в котором находится эта функция

Comment: @Санаев зачем файлу находиться в ресурсах, если его там нет? Даже если он там находится, то как может быть `IndexOutOfBoundsException` если файл не пустой?

Comment: @RomanC хотел бы, чтобы автор перенес файл в ресурсы.
Насчет exception возможно у автора несколько текстовых файлов size.txt и один из них пустой. Ну как вариант

Comment: Кому то не нравится мой ответ?:)